# Spring Data JPA read same Entity from multiple tables or views

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I try to read the same Entity from multiple tables (or views) with exactly the same columns. The views are aggregations based on the Entity resulting in the same Entity.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Table("bar")
public class Bar(){
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id; 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar") 
    private Set<Foo> foos;
}

@Entity
@Table("foo")
public class Foo(){
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;
   private int units;
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   private Bar bar; 

}
```

the view looks like this:

```
create view sum_foo_with_same_name as
  select
    sum(units) AS units,
    name AS name,
    bar_id AS bar_id
  from foo
  group by name, bar_id;
```

how can I read instances of Foo from both the table and the view?
I also need to get the referenced Bar instances.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it would be possible I think it is not a good idea to read this way. In the principle the entity is an information unit. Table is the entity persistence to store data when entity is gone from memory.

JPA can store one Entity in more than one table but this is not idea you want. This is rather for separate indexes, big data, performance etc.

I suggest to create a projection class (representing the view) with the same fields like Foo and create second, read only entity for loading data from view. After that you can create a mapper function to mapping data from table and/or view.